# can I turn off Chrome's "Page(s) Unresponsive" dialog?

Tags: google-chrome

Ideally for some pages. I get this message constantly in Chrome 39 for youtube pages. Happens at home and at work, so it's not a CPU problem, both systems have plenty of horsepower, more than enough to play 480p video.

I've tried turning on/off hardware accelaration. No change.

I also see this warning on other pages too. It's annoying because it's just a false positive -- the pages are working fine.

I'd like to completely disable it or just disable it for some pages. Are either of those possible?

Edit: Apparently fixed by the time v43 came out and I checked on this question again.

Answer (score 7):

Edit the Properties for a Chrome shortcut and add `--disable-hang-monitor` to the `Target:` line.  Close Chrome, use `taskmgr` to make sure there is no chrome.exe running, then always start Chrome with the modified shortcut.

> Suppresses hang monitor dialogs in renderer processes. This may allow slow unload handlers on a page to prevent the tab from closing, but the Task Manager can be used to terminate the offending process in this case.<sup>[peter.sh](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)</sup>

Comment: Suggested elsewhere, doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine here.  Make sure you edited the shortcut correctly (`--disable-hang-monitor` should be prefixed with a space and added outside the quoted argument). Also make sure that chrome.exe isn't already running.

Comment: Definitely didn't change anything: http://i.imgur.com/d4Xg2B6.png and http://i.imgur.com/ozaYbfK.png. Closed all my Chrome instances before adding that.

Comment: I just double checked this; the `disable-hang-monitor` switch definitely doesn't fix this in Chrome 39.

Comment: No idea why, sorry.  In any case, Google claims this bug is fixed in today's stable release, 39.0.2171.99

Comment: This option works for me in Chrome 39.0.2171.99. @jcollum, you might try [Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and make sure that your top-level Chrome instance does in fact have the full `--disable-hang-monitor` argument specified.

Comment: 39.0.2171.99 or later no longer needs the option

Answer (score -1):

According to [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNsuP1jlRP4) you should:

1. open Chrome,
2. go to Settings,
3. click "Show advanced settings".
4. Then you go to Privacy - Content Settings and check "Block third-party cookies and site data".

Otherwise, you could try running it in a different compatibility mode. You can do so by right-clicking: Chome.exe - Preferences - Compatibility. Now choose Windows 8. Hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: Worth a try but that was already checked. I can't run in Win8 compat because I'm on Win7.