# How to increase the time needed before "Page(s) Unresponsive" show? (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome

To prevent annoyance with Chrome's persistent "Page(s) Unresponsive" popup, I've disabled them using **[`--disable-hang-monitor`](https://superuser.com/a/863368/78897)**.

However, this has the effect of allowing a true webpage hang to simply hang forever. It simply refuses to close unless I force-quit using task manager (which is not a good idea as many other tabs will end up getting killed along with it).

Is there a way to make the "Page(s) Unresponsive" popup **show after a very long delay**, for example after a page has hanged for 10 minutes or more?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Google has been ignoring requests to implement this feature for over six years, so I wouldn't hold your breath.

 See: [How can I change the default website connection timeout in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/633648/how-can-i-change-the-default-website-connection-timeout-in-chrome)

I would focus on fixing the thing that makes the connection take THAT long instead of trying to increase the timeout time. You can try pinging the server, or something like that.

Comment: It happens also when one is debugging, and in the mean time Chrome is throwing this error every 30 secs.